# Graph y-axis by strings in C# Charts?

Tags: c#, .net, string, graph, charts

I want to make a graph where the x-values are DateTimes and the y-values are a fixed number of static strings, but it doesn't seem like C# series allows me to do that.

Another solution would be to graph by Numeric values and change the y-axis labels to strings, but I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Thanks,

Lenny

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790831/having-issues-with-plotting-polar-data-on-a-datetime-x-axis

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659095/draw-date-on-x-axis-and-time-on-y-axis-using-zedgraph-and-c-sharp

Comment: Which charting controls do you use?

Comment: I'm just using the built-in C# tools. The two related questions posted aren't really relevant because I need to graph non-numeric values on the y-axis.

Comment: You need to use [CustomLabels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456628.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)